# Swift XCode 7 UI how to test camera is on and picture taken

Tags: xcode7

I am new to Swift and XCode, and building an app that uses the camera to take pictures.

I would like to test that the camera is on, and also that I have effectively taken a picture.  How could I do that?

I am using XCode 7.3.1.